# GitHub CLI Download specific file from specific release

Tags: github, github-cli

I've tried multiple ways to download a specific File from a specific Release, but it doesn't work.

Windows Version:

```
gh version 1.6.2 (2021-02-23)
https://github.com/cli/cli/releases/tag/v1.6.2
```

`gh release view updates-2021-02-21 -R knah/VRCMods` returns:

```
updates-2021-02-21
knah released this about 11 days ago

  Refer to README for more info. New mod: True Shader Anticrash Changes:

  • Lag Free Screenshots - a bunch of different speedups, now uses less CPU too
  to encode screenshots
  • UI Expansion Kit - fix lags when toggling settings in some cases, add
  ability to update dropdown-styled settings, make modified ML check a bit more
  reliable
  • IKTweaks - fix crashes on some uncommon tracking setups
  • IKTweaks - potentially fixed some object disposed exceptions
  • Advanced Safety - add simple particle limiter
  • Advanced Safety - fix some audio effect being unnecessarily removed
  • Advanced Safety - reduce ugly stretching if skinned mesh bones are removed
  • View Point Tweaks - added forward compatibility with VRC beta update

  USE IT AT YOUR OWN RISK. Modding the client is against VRChat ToS. I am not
  responsible for any bans or other punishments you may get by using these
  mods!


Assets
AdvancedSafety.dll       38.50 KiB
IKTweaks.dll             122.50 KiB
LagFreeScreenshots.dll   18.50 KiB
TrueShaderAntiCrash.dll  158.00 KiB
UIExpansionKit.dll       264.50 KiB
ViewPointTweaker.dll     13.50 KiB

View on GitHub: https://github.com/knah/VRCMods/releases/tag/updates-2021-02-21
```

`gh release download updates-2021-02-21 -R knah/VRCMods` downloads all the Files in this commit.

---

The following requests result in the return of: `no assets match the file pattern`

- `gh release download -p 'UIExpansionKit.dll' updates-2021-02-21 -R knah/VRCMods`
- `gh release download updates-2021-02-21 -p 'UIExpansionKit.dll' -R knah/VRCMods`
- `gh release download updates-2021-02-21 -R knah/VRCMods -p 'UIExpansionKit.dll'`

**Question**: Is there a way to get this working?

Comment: On linux, I've tested with the same gh version, all 3 commands works for me

Comment: What shell are you using on Windows?  bash, CMD, PowerShell, or something else?

Comment: @bk2204 I used the cmd. I now tried git bash and it worked. Thank you ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@bk2204 Thanks for the Question.

What solved the problem was using any other shell that I have installed:

- PowerShell
- Git Bash